# Deploying to app engine without eclipse?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've got a python app and I want to deploy it. I'm using Aptana Studio 3. It's based on Eclipse but will not install the plugin due to dependancy issues. Basically I'm wondering what are my options for deploying my app outside of Eclipse?

Comment: Problems with installing Aptana Studio 3 are usually related to PyDev (which AS3 contins) being already installed. Try uninstalling PyDev (and previous versions of AS) prior to installing AS3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the appcfg tool included with the GAE SDK.

```
appcfg.py update path_to_app
```

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Uploading_the_App